# GRUB 2 scripting: convert device name in GRUB notation into a Linux device name

Tags: scripting, boot, grub2

I'm trying to use partition labels (or UUIDs, that does not matter) to select root partition without use of an initrd/initramfs.

With initramfs, this is fairly easy: `root=LABEL=...` or `root=/dev/disk/by-label/...` in the kernel arguments does the job.
However, without initramfs the above is not possible: the `LABEL=` notation is decoded by initramfs script, and `/dev/disk/by-label/...` symlinks are created by udev running from the initramfs. Only the `root=/dev/sdXY` notation is understood by the kernel itself.

However, GRUB supports shell-like scripting, and I think that it is somehow possible to write a GRUB 2 scriptlet that will generate `root=/dev/sdXY` string from a device label or UUID.

Especially, the command `search --label <label> --set ROOTDEV` will set variable `ROOTDEV` with a string like `hd0,gpt5` which points to the partition with given label. If I understand correctly (please correct me if I'm wrong) the order of devices in GRUB and kernel is the same, so `hd0` is `/dev/sda`, `hd1` is `/dev/sdb` and so on.

So here is a question: is there a way, from inside the GRUB 2 script, to convert `hd0,gpt5` into `/dev/sda5`? Exactly the `hd0` into `sda` part - the rest is easy with regexes.

Comment: No, the device in GRUB and kernel has no reason to be the same.

Comment: You cannot make a purely textual translation: GRUB has to follow BIOS device numbering, and the kernel doesn't, so there is no intrinsic connection between the `a` in Linux's `sda` and the `0` in Grub's `hd0`. You can't do the conversion inside Grub as far as I know, but you can do it from `/boot/grub/device.map` when generating the Grub configuration file.

Comment: @Gilles: dammit. So is initrd unavoidable in this case?..

Answer (score 0):

When Grub2 is on a USB stick (that USB stick has no Linux intalled on it, so grub.cfg mut be manually created and edited), the data partition literal changes, depending on how many internal and external devices are connected, and if hardware boots on UEFI or BIOS modes.

In some lines i need to have a parameter in the form of /dev/sd$#, not GRUB style, it must point to such partition data (the literal is not allways the same, it depends a lot on the computer i boot with such USB).

With GRUB search command i can get the literal, but in GRUB style.

I do not know how to use regular expressions inside grub.cfg file to change hd# to sd$, neither to change ',msdos#' or ',gpt#' to #.

Maybe a link to regular expresions in grub.cfg can help.